# Signing out of Stack Exchange does not sign me out of my email provider

Tags: support, openid

I have noticed that by signing on to Stack Overflow, I am also signed on to my email account. But when I log *out*, it only logs me out of the *site* without logging me out of my email. This means I am running around saying "hey, you should XSS me". Is this specific to the way OpenID behaves, or is it specific to the way Stack Overflow implemented it?

Comment: @Christopher, how is this a feature request? And why using backticks? Those are for code! (Peek into the HTML if you disagree.)

Comment: My mistake, rollback'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OpenID. You need to be logged in to your OpenID provider to be logged in to here, but this site has no control over if you're logged in to your OpenID provider.

Comment: At minimum you should be presented with the option to just log out of the site or log back out of the open id provider.

Comment: SO can't log you out of your OpenID provider. It has no way of doing that. But on the other hand, you *need* to log *in* through your provider to be able to use SO, which means you have to manually log out when you're done. Pain in the ass, yes, but there's nothing SO can do about it.

Comment: They could give a link to the same url I get when I go to google and actually log out.