# Google Single Sign On Concerns

Tags: discussion, google

Just discovered this as I used the Google ID signin process to get into SO. If I sign into SO using my Google ID, I am instantly logged into every other place where my Google ID is used.

I can view my mail, my google docs, and I show up as logged in on Google+ (doesn't matter because no one uses that). But it leads me to this question - Why does logging in on StackOverflow with my Google ID automatically log me into every other Google service? I didn't want to log in to any of the other Google stuff, only StackOverflow. If I want to stay offline in Google+ and logout, I'm logged out of Stackoverflow. Is there no way to log me in here with my Google ID without logging me in on every other application?

Comment: That is how cookies work. To be entirely fair, this is non-intuitive for non-web-developers.

Comment: Related: [Signing out of Stack Exchange does not sign me out of my email provider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/signing-out-of-stack-exchange-does-not-sign-me-out-of-my-email-provider).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Logging in to SO via Google involves logging in to Google. Once you're logged in to Google, it verifies that you've granted SO access to your credentials, checks everything, and logs you in to SO. However, at that point, it doesn't log you back *out* of Google... that just sits in the background. You can log back out of Google and it won't affect SO. Personally, that's what I do... log in via google, and once I'm in, I log back out of Google and resume browsing SO.

Comment: Precisely and well said.

Comment: This is in additon to @eykanal's excellent post: Bookmark `http://www.google.com/accounts/Logout`, and click it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click to open it in a new tab, preferably to avoid interruption)