# Why am I automatically logged back in after I've already logged out?

Tags: bug, login

I'm trying to log out of Stack Overflow.  I can't.  It used to work when I had MyOpenId credentials.  But I just created a new Stack Exchange account.  I can choose the down arrow next to my name, and choosing "log out", then clicking the "Log out" button.  Stack overflow then says I'm logged out.  But if I choose to log in again, when I choose to log in via a Stack Exchange account I just get a "log in" button that works without asking me my username or password.

How the flip do I really log out?

If it matters, I'm using Chrome.

(This may or may not be a dupe of [I can't log out of the Stack Exchange network.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139036/i-cant-log-out-of-the-stack-exchange-network)  - it sounds similar).

**Edited to add:**  This is NOT a dupe of [Signing out of Stack Exchange does not sign me out of my email provider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/signing-out-of-stack-exchange-does-not-sign-me-out-of-my-email-provider) because I'm not using an external OAuth provider, I'm using Stack Exchange's own account system.  And AFAICT there's no way to log out of Stack Exchange's own account system?

Comment: That's because you're still logged in to the provider itself e.g. gmail. Try logging out there as well.

Comment: So how do I log out of Stack Exchange?  To be clear, my oauth provider is Stack Exchange itself, NOT gmail.

Comment: I'd give it six to eight weeks to log you out.

Comment: Do you see logout option here? https://openid.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stack Exchange OpenID is still a separate credential provider, so the advice in the other thread applies.